# In gnu parallel how to specify the name of result files/directories?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have an executable that accepts two floating point numbers as command line arguments.
I am using gnu parallel to run multiple instances of my program with different values of these floating point parameters. The arguments are present as 2 columns in a file. Example:

```
1.1 2.2
3.3 4.4
```

I tried to use `parallel --results` to store the outputs systematically in a directory structure. However, the generated files have names like the following, as the argument values are doubles:

```
outfilestderr?1?1.1?2?2.2
outfilestdout?1?1.1?2?2.2
outfilestderr?1?3.3?2?4.4
outfilestdout?1?3.3?2?4.4
```

is there a way to specify the format for names of generated files/directories? For example, can I name each combination of arguments by its order in the input file?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have found a bug. --results should save in outdir/1/val1/2/val2/stdout and outdir/1/val1/2/val2/stderr

Please post a reproducible example on parallel@gnu.org.